# Passing parameters across multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, get, parameter-passing

This is a very generic question but in my case I'm working with ASP and C#. I have the following situation:

**Page 1:**

two html selects, both with classes `nameSelect`, `surnameSelect`.  When the user changes either of these selects, I put the value inside a hidden field called `hfName` and `hfSurname`. Then when I click a button which may go to a detailed view, I generate the link with javascript and pass `&name=111&surname=222` via GET.

**Page 2:**

I already know which parameters can be passed on this page so I have two hidden fields: `hfName` and `hfSurname`.  I retrieve the values from the GET and if the user goes back with the breadcrumbs I send the user back to the previous page with `&name=111&surname=222` and this auto-sets the selects to the previous values.

**Normal situation:**

In a normal situation Page 2 would not use `name` or `surname` as parameters for the content so the parameters are not a problem.  If page 2 also has two selects called `nameSelect` and `surnameSelect`, it's not a problem.  The user can change these values on page 2 and when I return back to page 1 the values can be updated e.g. to `333` and `444`.

**The problem:**

The main problem occurs when I have to pass multiple versions of `name` at the same time. This can happen if page 2 is a list of people, so clicking on a row may require the passing of the `name` parameter (remember this is an example). This means that if I return to page 1 the `name` value will be set but not because I selected it from the select but because I clicked the button on page 2.  This is not correct because the scope of the `name` parameter when clicking the button in the row is only inside the detail page (page 3).

**Possible solutions**

The first solution I thought of was adding a keyword before parameters which aren't used for content e.g. `filterName` and `filterSurname`.  This creates it's own problems as I will sometimes want the `name` / `surname` values to be used in the content. If I do a mix and only sometimes put `filterName` and `surname` then it becomes very difficult to manage because I have a many different parameters with different names.

Is there some really obvious solution I am missing here or is it really not possible to make the system any more simple than I have already made it?

Thanks

Comment: What i would suggest is make **class (DTO Object)** and define the property as per your requirement and then pass it in method as parameter using **Post** rather than **Get**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment I would create a class with a default settings and save it to the session, then from here on out I would check the session data that, if it doesn't exist set it to a new class if it does use the value from the session.

Get or Post does not really matter.  I just would then have code on the page load that would load the class and then go through the get or post variables update the class and then save it back to the session.